# Calling PHP function with button

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, ajax, function

I have been researching for 2 days on what is wrong with my button and so its come time to give up and ask for help.

I am not very experienced in PHP/AJAX or jQuery and so all the answers I find are too complicated for my understanding thus far.  All I am trying to do is call the answer (a php function) to a question with a "see answer" button.

I have a question.php which displays the question and I have an answer.php which displays the answer. When called manually they work well but when I introduce the code for a button it does not:

```
function getAOTD() {
    var request = $.ajax({
        url: "answer.php",
        type: "GET",            
        dataType: "html"
    });

    request.done(function(msg) {
        $("#answer").html(msg);         
    });

    request.fail(function(jqXHR, textStatus) {
        alert( "Request failed: " + textStatus );
    });
}
```

I am mostly interested in figuring out what I need to learn rather than having someone else simply debug for me.  My immediate concern is the "html" from the example I built off of but after troubleshooting I haven't made any progress.  I appreciate any and all help!

EDIT:
This is how I am calling the script:

```
<div id="answer"><center><input type="button" value="See Answer" onclick="getAOTD()" /></center></div>
```

Comment: What is your question?

Comment: When I try to call the function with the button its not working.

Comment: What behaviour are you observing? Are you getting any errors?

Comment: Nothing happens.  If you click the button, it looks like it was pushed, and then nothing happens.

Comment: Be sure to make use of the developer tools in your browser, specifically the console. Makes things like this much easier.

Answer (score 0):

Assuming your PHP script is returning what you want, using [`.load()`](http://api.jquery.com/load/) is probably easier:

```
function getAOTD() { 
    $("#answer").load('/answer.php'); 
}
```

This assumes that answer.php is a sibling of the current page and only returns a partial HTML snippet.

Comment: This doesn't work for me and so I think i'm narrowing down my problem to #answer

Comment: Can you elaborate on "doesn't work"? Do you see errors in the JavaScript console?

Comment: Its doing the same thing it was earlier, push the button, nothing happens.  I do not see any errors.  I have tried this in several browsers thinking this could be the problem, but its all the same.

Comment: Add a console.log ('clicked!') to the function above and then tell me what you see.

Comment: Also, remove that `<center>` tag; it's deprecated and shouldn't be used. Add a `style="text-align: center;"` to the answer `<div>` if you want centered text.